# Angular ui bootstrap pagination as reusable component across different tables

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have 4 bootstrap tables used in my angularjs application and i am using angular ui bootstrap pagination directive across these tables and used watch to monitor the page change in respective controllers.
Is there other ways to use angular-ui-bootstrap pagination directive as a reusable component(one code used across multiple places)????for example as directive.

Comment: yes, you can check ng-table module which is having more control with bootstrap style

Comment: i want to use angular-ui-bootstrap pagination directive as reusable component(create custom directive using bootstrap pagination directive) not ng-table.

Comment: Hey did you applied that? Do you have code?